# Laravel API Wrapper- Not able to find auto loaded packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package, wrapper

I'm currently trying to build my first API Wrapper for Laravel but having some Problems with auto loading the actual PHP-Lirbary.

I'm receiving the following error when I try to Access the Widget in my view.

**Error:**

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class 'Uploadcare\Api' not found
```

**View**

```
{!! app()->uploadcare->widget->getInputTag('file_input') !!}
```

My package ServiceProvider is looking like this.

**UploadcareServiceProvider**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Uploadcare\Api as Uploadcare;


class UploadcareServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/config/uploadcare.php' => config_path('uploadcare.php'),
        ]);
    }



    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->singleton('uploadcare', function($app) {

            $publicKey = config('uploadcare.public_key');
            $privateKey = config('uploadcare.private_key');

            return new Uploadcare($publicKey, $privateKey);

        });
    }


    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            Uploadcare::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

And in my packages composer.json file im requring the package.

**Packages composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "uploadcare/uploadcare-php": "^2.1"
    }
```

In the Vendor folder of the package I'm able to find the **Uploadcae\Api** Class so i'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

**packages composer.json**

```
{
        "name": "company/uploadcare",
        "description": "An uploadcre integration for Laravel",
        "type": "library",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Stan Barrows",
                "email": ""
            }
        ],
        "require-dev": {
            "orchestra/testbench": "^3.5",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.3"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Company\\Uploadcare\\": "src/"
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "providers": [
                    "Company\\Uploadcare\\UploadcareServiceProvider"
                ]
            }
        },
        "require": {
            "uploadcare/uploadcare-php": "^2.1"
        }
    }
```

**main project composer.json file**

```
 {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "type": "project",


        "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "path",
                "url": "packages/company/uploadcare"
            }
        ],

        "require": {
            "php": ">=7.0.0",
            "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
            "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
            "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
            "laravelnews/laravel-twbs4": "^1.3",
            "ramsey/uuid": "^3.7"
        },


        "require-dev": {
            "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
            "laravel/dusk": "^2.0",
            "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
            "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ],

            "psr-4": {
                "Genusshaus\\": "app/",
                "Smart6ate\\Roles\\": "packages/company/roles/src",
                "Smart6ate\\Uploadcare\\": "packages/company/uploadcare/src/"


            },
            "files": ["tests/Helpers/functions.php"]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }


        },

        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": [
                ]
            }
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate"
            ],
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true,
            "optimize-autoloader": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add an entry in your composer.json for psr-4 class mapping? `"Vendor\\Namespace\\": "src/"`

Comment: My package is auto loaded via:"Company\\Uploadcare\\": "packages/company/uploadcare/src"

Comment: You're missing the trailing slash on `src/`

Comment: When i require the packages in my main repository it works, but I would like to load it within my package. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yeah just like i posted earlier. Put it in your packages composer.json file. `"Company\\Uploadcare\\":"src/"`

Comment: When I remove the package from my main repository , event its declared like you mentioned in the packages composer.json - I'm receiving the error: Class 'Uploadcare\Api' not found . I'll publish my packages composer in the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh add a repositories entry for it. `"repositories": [{ "type":"path",    "url":"packages/company/uploadcare"}]`....  https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Comment: In the main project? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah main project. It'll create a symlink in the vendor directory

Comment: Still no success, I've updated my main-project composer.json in the question above. Maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: You need to require your package in the main project too. `"company/uploadcare":"dev-master" ` add that in the "require" section

Comment: Oukey perfect thank you, will try this out. Can i remove the PSR4-Autoload?   "Smart6ate\\Uploadcare\\": "packages/company/uploadcare/src/",

Comment: Perfect that was working excellent! Thanks very much for your help!